# ValueAccessor is empty in the custom binding (knockoutjs & googlemap)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

I have a view model which get  places via ajax request. These places are coming, but when I try to use it in the custom binding google map, valueAccessor is empty.
Can you explain to me what  wrong I'm doing?

```js
var  MapViewModel  = function(){

 var self = this;
    var yelp = new YelpDataProvider();
    var categories = [{"id": 1,"name" : "Bars"}, {"id": 2,"name" : "Gyms"}];
    var addresses = [];
 self.places = ko.observableArray();
 self.selectCategory  = ko.observable();
 
    self.selectCategory.subscribe(function(category) {
     var _filtered = addresses;

     if(typeof category != "undefined")
      _filtered = _.where(_filtered, {'categoryId': category});
     
        yelp.getDataForPlaces(_filtered).then(function(place){
   self.places(place);
  });
    });

 yelp.getDataForPlaces(addresses).then(function(place){
  self.places(place);
 })

}


ko.bindingHandlers.googlemap = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
     debugger;
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        console.log(value);
        console.log(valueAccessor());
        var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(value[0].location.coordinate.latitude,
             value[0].location.coordinate.longitude);

    var myWrapper = $("#wrapper");
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
      myWrapper.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
         // code to execute after transition ends
         google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      });
    });

    // create the map
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: centerPoint,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
      },
      navigationControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions)

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.close();
  });


  _.each(value,function(place){
   var _point = new google.maps.LatLng(place[0].location.coordinate.latitude,
                 place[0].location.coordinate.longitude);
    var marker = createMarker(point, place.businesses[0].id,
     businesses[0].snippet_text)
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
       infowindow.close();
      });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(MapViewModel);
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas" data-bind="googlemap: places"></div>
```

Comment: You are not creating your view model correctly, the `new` keyword is missing. It should look like `ko.applyBindings(new MapViewModel());`

Comment: Anyway, problem isn't solving.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why aren't you able to access "places", but below is another way you can try accessing it inside of your binding handler -

1. Update the binding in your html to pass in the viewModel -

   ```
   <div id="map_canvas" data-bind="googlemap: places, viewModel: $root"></div>
   ```
2. Include "allBindingAccessors" as a parameter to your handler -

   ```
   ko.bindingHandlers.googlemap = {
       init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
           var viewModel = allBindingsAccessor().viewModel;
           var value = viewModel.places();
           // Do more stuff
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this works :P